# How take classes with some annotation in specific package

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I write own DI/IoC library on java. I want to take classes which have some annotation (e.g. my own annotaion) in given package to scan, like in Spring IoC. But reflection from jdk is not appropriate, because i can't traverse through package. I took decision to use SimpleFileVisitor to take classes, but i don't want to use this "crutch". How to take classes with specific annotation in given package?

Comment: "But reflection from jdk is not appropriate, because i can't traverse through package". What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: I have package to scan e.g. "com.app." and i must take all classes in this package with custom annotation @MyAnnotation. And reflection for jdk doesn't allow it.

Comment: @CKing Java has no methods for listing all of the classes in a package.  It’s not even possible, since a class that has never been loaded does not exist as far as the JVM is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [Reflection](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained) lib form google.